# AndEngine. Can't make the sprite move using DigitalOnScreenControl

Tags: andengine

I'm new to AndEngine. I'm trying to move my sprite in PhysicsWorld using DigitalOnScreenControl. But it seems like my sprite cannot move in PhysicsWorld. Without PhysicsWorld the player is controlled correctly, but if I call

`this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(myPlayer, body, true, true));`

it stops moving. In other words I see the animation like it moves is performed, but it doesn't change its position. Please, advice.

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/7zE8Jrbg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used the `DigitalOnScreenControl` with `PhysicsWorld`, I didn't use `PhysicsHandler` to move my object,

I mean that I didn't move the object like that:

```
 physicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX * 200, pValueY * 200);
```

however, I did use the `body.setLinearVelocity(....)` function to move the body
the body will move with the sprite connected to it, because you constructed a `PhysicsConnector` between your sprite and your body, using the line :

```
 this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(myPlayer, body, true, true));
```

so whenever you move your body, your sprite will be moved too.